# Is it proper to say: "I wasn't allowed in(side)"?

Tags: grammar

Is it proper to say: "I wasn't allowed in(side)"?
Can ''to'' be omitted? - 'I wasn't allowed TO go inside'

Comment: No, "to" cannot be omitted. If you omit "to" your sentence reads "I wasn't allowed go inside" which is not grammatical.

Comment: I asked whether the sentence ''I was not allowed inside" is correct. Btw I agree that of yours is incorrect )

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's correct to say *allow someone to do something*, *be allowed somewhere* is also correct:

> No passengers are **allowed** **inside** the cockpit while we're in the air.
>
> Excuse me, mobile phones are not **allowed** **on** the plane.
>
> She's not **allowed** **on** the premises.

That's why you can say "I wasn't allowed inside," or "I wasn't allowed to go inside."